# Get text from an element using its attribute in a XPath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here's the XML code:

```
    <perfil>
        <person idP="P1">
            <studied refidEs="Es3"/>
    .
    .
    .

    <schools>
        <school idEs="Es3">
            <name>Name of the school</name>
        </school>
```

In the beginning of the document I have a reference made to a certain school, and in the end I have the name of the school with its proper id. In the XPath expression, I have to mention what's in the beginning (e.g. `perfil/person/studied[@refidEs]`), and I want it to show the name of the school. The thing is that, when I use the expression on the example, it only shows the id of the school. Even if I end with `/text()`, it shows no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath expression will select the string value of the `name` of the `school` with an `@idEs` attribute value of `Es3`:

```
string(//school[@idEs='Es3']/name)
```

In the case of the provided XML (assuming it's complete, well-formed, and no other `school` elements with the same `Es3` attribute value), this will select:

```
Name of the school
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and yes, it's the complete, well-formed and it's the only element with that attribute value. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you target an element by it's ID with xpaths:

```
//school[@idEs='Es3']/name[1]
```

Xpaths allow you to select any attribute this way. For example, You can substitue `@idEs=` for any other attribute selector such as `@class=`. The next part gets the value of the first `<name>` element, which is what you are trying to target.

Take a look at this for further clarification http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderGriffin your answer was really helpfull, as well as that website!